# Copy selected value of last table row, to the new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, jquery-selectors

In my script I'll add a table row when the user click on "add" button, and I want to set the valued of the new table row (who has input box and dropbown select) to the same of the old last row.
I'll try this script, but it fails:

```
$('input[name=add]').live('click', function()
{
    var y = $('table tbody tr').length;
    var x = $('table tbody tr td').length;
    var last = $('table tbody tr:last');
    //alert(last.find('select:first').val());
    var value;
    last.clone(true).insertAfter(last);
    //alert(y);
    $('table tbody tr:last').find('td:last').html('<input type="button" class="btn" name="delete" value=" - " />');

    var col =$('table tbody').find('tr').eq(y).find('td');
    col.eq(x).each(function(index, element) {
        if(col.eq(index).has('input'))
        {
            value=$(this).val();
            $('table tbody tr:last').find('td').eq(index).find('input').val(value);
        }elseif(col.eq(index).has('select'))
        {
            value = col.eq(index).find('select').val();
            $('table tbody tr:last').find('td').eq(index).find('select').val(value);
        }
    });
```

it only works for the first of input box.
The table row is this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="article" /></td>
        <td>
            <select name="colore">
                <option value="nabuk">Nabuk</option>
                <option value="nero">Nero</option>
                <option value="blu">Blu</option>
                <option value="rosso">Rosso</option>
            </select>
         </td>
        <td>
            <select name="fondo">
                <option value="gomma">Gomma</option>
                <option value="cuoio">Cuoio</option>
                <option value="legno">Legno</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="numero">
                <option value="36">36</option>
                <option value="37">37</option>
                <option value="38">38</option>
                <option value="39">39</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="input-mini" min="1" max="200" name="qnt" step="1" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need such huge code, just try this:

```
$('table').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('input[name=add]').on('click', function() {
    var cloned = $('table tr:last').clone(true); // clone last row
    // looping over last row's inputs
    $('table tr:last').find(':input').each(function() {
        // set values to cloned inputs same previous
        cloned.find(':input[name=' + this.name + ']').val(this.value);
    });
    $('table > tbody').append(cloned); // append the cloned row to table
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkdGW/3/)**

​

#### According to comment

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[name=add]', function() {
    var cloned = $('table tbody tr:last').clone(true);
    cloned.find('td:last').html('<input type="button" class="btn" name="delete" value=" - " />');
    $('table tbody tr:last').find('select').each(function() {
        cloned.find('select[name^=' + this.name.replace('[]','') + ']').val(this.value);
    });

    $('table tbody').append(cloned);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y3qg8/1/)**

Comment: Do you need to set the input values for the new row? I was under the impression `.clone()` copied them anyway.

Comment: @JamWaffles jQuery will not set previous value to cloned input, its a bug. check this http://jsfiddle.net/pkdGW/4/.. you will see some input don't update

Comment: @user1432059 would you please explain the problem?

Comment: after you have add a row, is showed a button on the last td of each row (except the last one row) where the name is not the same I've write in the javascript! and the values of each new row aren't not the same of the upper one!

Comment: @user1432059 Its just working fine and what value you're expecting in that last button?

Comment: have you tried it http://jsfiddle.net/y3qg8/ ?
if I put in a row 123-Nero-Legno-28-4, the new one must have 123-nero-Legno-28-4- "-" the last button must have a - and stay for the button which delete the specific row

Comment: but the new line doesn't have all the values equals to the upper row

Comment: comunities could be better if are composed only by people like you! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code using which you can accomplish what you want, you can optimize further but it's does what you need

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[name=add]',function()
{
    var last = $('table tbody tr:last');
    var value;
    last.clone(true).insertAfter(last);
    $('table tbody tr:last')
         .find('td:last')
         .html('<input type="button" class="btn" name="delete" value=" - " />');
    var col = last.find('td');
    col.each(function(index, element) {
        if($(this).find(':text').length)
        {
            value=$(this).find(':text').val();
            $('table tbody tr:last')
                  .find('td').
                     eq(index).find('input').val(value);
        }else if($(this).find('select').length)
        {
            value = $(this).find('select').val();
            $('table tbody tr:last')
                  .find('td').eq(index)
                  .find('select').val(value);
        }
                   });
});

$('table').on('click','.btn',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});​
```

I have used [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on) as `$.live` is depreciated now.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/pkdGW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery clone unfortunately does not deep copy selectedIndex. Here's a laconic workaround, although it may be slow with large documents:

```
$("table tr:last select").change(function() {
    $("table tr:last").find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
});

$('button[name=add]').live('click', function() {
    $("table tr:last").find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
    $("table tr:last").clone().appendTo("tbody");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8RNb/1/

Comment: I've an error on your solution... it doesn't work proprely :S